# Build and use generic list?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0, generic-list

Can anyone help me figure out how I could simplify this code, without using an `ArrayList`?

```
List<Pair> material = new List<Pair>();
List<string> list = new List<string>();

string tempStr;
int integer = -1;
foreach (string s in ((string)Value).Split(new char[1] { ',' }))
{
  if (int.TryParse(s, out integer))
  {
     tempStr = NameValue.AllKeys[integer];

     if (someCondition == true)
     {
        material.Add(new Pair(tempStr, integer));
     }
     else
     {
        list.Add(tempStr);
     }
  }
}
if(someCondition == true)
{
  return material.ExtensionMethodForLists();
}
else
{
  return list.ExtensionMethodForLists();
}
```

When I've tried something like (below) I get an error for not initializing an implicityly-typed variable.

```
var list;
if(someCondition == true)
{
  list = new List<Pair>();
}
else
{
  list = new List<string>();
}
```

Comment: list cannot be of two different types.

Comment: @mathepic - I wasn't sure if I could use generics in here somehow to help

Comment: You need both types to inherit from a common interface/type. Wrap pair and string in types with a common interface/base type.

Comment: Well if you notice, he's only using one list...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using different types, you would need to use a non-generic type for the variable:

```
IList list;
if(someCondition == true)
{
  list = new List<Pair>();
}
else
{
  list = new List<string>();
}
```

or

```
IList list = someCondition ? (IList)new List<Pair>() : new List<string>();
```

Personally, I'm not sure it is a great design, but it satisfies the requirement.

Comment: Only trouble with the non-generic IList is that working with it as such is not far from using ArrayList.

Comment: Completely over-thought using IList, but would you have any recommendation for a better design?

Comment: @KeithS - not quite; you can't put a `Pair` in a `List<string>` by accident, even though it is exposed as `IList`

Comment: @Brett, the better design I would go for is not returning types as different as `List<string>` and `List<Pair>`. *At most*, I would want to return `List<ISomeInterface>`, but even that is not possible with these given types.

Comment: @Anthony - in the end, the `ExtensionMethodForLists()` builds a `DataTable` to be passed to SQL as a user defined table type, so really the return for both of them is a DataTable

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this actually simplifies, but something like:

```
    public DataTable ParseToTable(string Value)
    {
        if (someCondition)
            return ParseInternal<Pair>(Value, (s, i) => new Pair(s, i));
        else
            return ParseInternal<string>(Value, (s, i) => s);
    }

    private DataTable ParseInternal<T>(string Value, Func<string,int,T> newItem)
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();

        string tempStr;
        int integer = -1;
        foreach (string s in ((string)Value).Split(new char[1] { ',' }))
        {
            if (int.TryParse(s, out integer))
            {
                tempStr = NameValue.AllKeys[integer];
                list.Add(newItem(tempStr, integer));
            }
        }
        return list.ExtensionMethodForLists();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use `var` you must assign the value immediately. Otherwise, as @Marc suggests is perfect... (well, as he says - satisfies the requirement)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that would in Python or some other dynamically typed language. Though if you are using .net 4.0 you could use the dynamic keyword instead of var.

But, you're using C# which is meant to be strongly typed and the dynamic keyword is really meant to interface with dynamically typed languages and if the type system is getting in your way, you should reconsider your design. Also, if you do really need to manage two types of collections like that you should wrap it in a class and hide such gory details from the client code.